# видео проигрывается без звука

Tags: javascript, html, аудио

я написал код чтобы видео проигрывала при открытии сайта и закрывалась по его окончанию.
но видео воспроизводится без звука! Помогите со звуком, мне нужен этот звук.

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="VID_20230214_113422.mp4" autoplay muted="false"></video>

<script>
        const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    
            
            video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
              video.pause();
              video.style.display = "none";
            });
            </script>
            
    <script>
    const video1 = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.style.position = 'absolute';
video.style.left = '0';
video.style.top = '0';
video.style.width = '100%';
video.style.height = '100%';

        </script>
        
        <script>window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    video.play();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, **запрещено** включить аудио в начале, без взаимодействия пользователя. Если будет видео, оно будет играть без звука.

Comment: Да и вообще `muted="false"` это тот же самый `muted` - то есть "без звука".